# Does tensorflow-federated support decision tree training model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

Going over the tutorials for TFF (tensorflow-federated), it seems that performing federated averaging and gradient descent iterations using TFF is well understood and can accomplished easily. However, for other training scenarios such as decision tree training it is not clear to me whether such an implementation is readily available. In particular, does the TF-DF (tensorflow decision forest) integrates well with TFF. If so, does anyone have an example for implementing a regression tree training? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

While TensorFlow Federated's [Federated Learning API](http://tensorflow.org/federated/federated_learning) provides pre-canned algorithms using gradient based methods (e.g. the FedAvg algorithm), TFF also has as a [Federated Core API](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/federated_core) which is agnostic to any particular machine learning paradigm.

This lower-level API is what is used to implement the algorithms in `tff.learning` and can be used to implement federated decision tree flavored algorithms. In the tutorial [Building Your Own Federated Learning Algorithm](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/building_your_own_federated_learning_algorithm), one could possible change the how a "model" is defined, and use something other than Keras.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. This is not an answer, more of a comment but I do not have the reputation, so I'm answering instead.

I've been trying to wrap a tfdf model, and it seems to work, except that I keep getting the same accuracy. https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/3847

I think the problem might be that tff is best suited for models that are Sequential in the sense that the model needs to use gradients to optimize the model parameters like a loss function. This is typical of neural network and gradient descent models.

Well, after doing some digging my teammate & I found that "Unlike Backpropagation, the training of RF does not "transmit" the loss gradient to from its output to its input." https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests/api_docs/python/tfdf/keras/RandomForestModel

Then with some more digging, we found this interesting looking tfdf model that uses gradient descent to optimize the model by "transmitting" outputs back into inputs! https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests/api_docs/python/tfdf/keras/GradientBoostedTreesModel

Currently going to try it and will let yall know if this was resolved. Hope this helped any future Privacy Engineers out there, cause this took a week to research and no one talks about it. Still might not work but it makes sense ;)

[EDIT]
Better answer here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/3847

Comment: TF-DF author here: Correct, Tensorflow Federated does not support TF-DF. Since Decision Forests are fundamentally different from Neural Networks, the same primitives (gradient descent in particular) simply do not apply. However, distributed training of TF-DF models on HUGE datasets is possible out-of-the-box, see the examples in the repository: https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/blob/main/examples/distributed_hyperparameter_optimization.py
https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/blob/main/examples/distributed_training.py